# Movie about an asteroid hitting the Earth. A couple sit on the porch to watch

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to remember the name of a weird movie about a meteor hitting the Earth.

There was a couple in a house with another woman (she may have been the mistress?) And maybe a kid? The whole premise of the movie was these people in this house they know the asteroid is coming so they are like saying goodbye, then at the end they take some pills and sit on the back porch to watch it hit.

This was a VERY odd movie, probably a B-movie. The whole thing is just in this house. It struck me as one of those weird Nicole Kidman type movies.

I have no idea who was in it but I *think* it came out in the mid 90's.

Comment: So not Melancholia then?

Comment: Some details remind me of [Timescape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timescape_(1992_film)).

Comment: I just watched that trailer and maybe . It looks kinda familiar but  I was thinking the whole movie was just in a house. Im gonbba watch it and see. Thank you so much for ur fast answer.

Comment: is it [deep impact](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120647/)?

Answer (score 13):

Could this be **[Melancholia](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1527186/)** from 2011? Not a B-Movie and not 1990s, but it does take place in a large family house, set against the backdrop of a large planet (not a meteor) hitting the Earth. There are multiple instances where people discuss, and then take suicide pills.

The final scene actually depicts the planet hitting. Several of the main characters sit in the garden and watch it happen.

Answer (score 0):

It reminds me of Melancholia as well.  There were plenty of porch scenes, but in the final scene:

> The husband commits suicide and leaves his wife alone to face death without him. So, the little boy (his son) and the two main characters (women) go out into the field and build a magical teepee to protect themselves and the child.  This is done so that the child has nothing to fear and he is encircled by complete love. As they hold hands and shut their eyes; one sister weaves a beautiful story. Then there is a flash and the world ends...

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This is already identified in the existing answer.  You shouldn't repeat an existing identification unless you have something substantial to add.